# Problem in creating one-shot impulse circuit

Tags: 555

I am a student in university and I have a problem to be solved.

I have to design a circuit that gives just one pulse (not periodic signal) when the 220V source is active. I will give 220V to the circuit and out will be one-second high. And I want to take feedback just one time even if source is connected. I tried 555 timer with one-shot impulse but it didn't work for me. Also if it is possible output must be 8-12 volt.

Thank you very much. Here is my circuit

[image]

Comment: Precisely and completely, what 555 circuit did you try and what did it do that you classed as "didn't work for me"

Comment: Did you input 220V into a 555 timer?

Comment: No, i just convert 220 to 12 then give it to the circuit

Comment: In Proteus isis it is working but in real does not working

Comment: Is your circuit always powered up, or only when the 220V source is active? How are you getting the 220V to trigger the 555? Why do you have a diode across the output?

Comment: It is powered up only when 220V source is active.220V is always active to the input of circuit. I dont have any Idea to trigger the 555. Diode is just for indication a relay will be connected

Comment: For a start, the diode is a terrible dummy load. Use eg a resistor. When you provide the WHOLE circuit we may be able to help you. So far you have been asked about the circuit but have not provided all of it. If YOU do not know what is wrong or where the fault is you also cannot say that the parts that you leave out are unimportant.

Comment: Whole circuit is the above circuit. Diode is just for demonstration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work for you, and the LTspice schematic is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z3outr09vqyjz22/Pulse%20on%20power-up.asc) if you want to play with the circuit.

[image]

Comment: sorry what is V1 here

Comment: V1 is the 12 volt DC source you made from the 240 volt mains.

Comment: how can use 220v directly with that circuit by the way it is working :) thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome :-).  Do you mean how to make the circuit generate a single pulse by just connecting it to the mains?  Do you care about isolation?

Comment: yes exactly what I want isolation can be done :) I will connect 220V and drive the circuit. Should I create a transformer circuit or is there any other way for that? And is it possible to drive the same circuit with 5V instead of 12V. Maybe lots of question sorry for that.

Comment: A transformer supply would be one way to do it, but there are others. Yes, it's possible to do it all with 5 volts.  If you post your questions as questions instead of comments, it'll be easier to answer them.

Comment: do you want me to ask a new question under this question or new question ? which one of them do you want me to do ?

Comment: Ask a new question, please. :-)